# Use OpenShift secret in OC Command

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Say I have an OpenShift command such as this:

```
$ oc new-app openshift/postgresql-92-centos7 \
    -e POSTGRESQL_USER=user \
    -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=db \
    -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password
```

Instead of typing in the password, is there a way to use the secret that are already stored in OpenShift?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there does not be a way to directly inject secrets when using oc new-app.

There is a issue on [github](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/22881) which requested exactly this feature, however it has been closed without any additional information and the official [openshift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/application_lifecycle/new_app.html) has no information about this feature as well.

you can always change the openshift resources after they have been created with oc new-app. or you us `oc create/apply -f your-resource.yaml` and provide your own yaml file instead of using the new-app mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your deployment initially without specifying the environment variables on the oc new-app command and later, if you already have secret/configmaps created, inject them to dpeloyment/deploymentconfig using
oc set env command.

if the secret/configmap need to be created, create them and then execute oc set env --from=secret/mysecret dc/<dc_name> to set the required environment variables/values.

You can also run oc new-app openshift/postgresql-92-centos7 -o yaml > myapp.yaml and save the output. The yaml file can now be edited and under Containers, append the required ENV information and then do oc create -f / oc apply -f to the yaml file.